# Python - matrix multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have an array y with shape (n,), I want to compute the inner product matrix, which is a n * n matrix
However, when I tried to do it in Python

```
np.dot(y , y)
```

I got the answer n, this is not what I am looking for
I have also tried:

```
np.dot(np.transpose(y),y)
np.dot(y, np.transpose(y))
```

I always get the same answer n

Comment: Do note that the `shape` of `x.T` is the same as that of `x`. This is because x is a one-dimensional array. You want to use 2-d arrays. 

Try using `np.reshape` to make x 2 dimensional.

Comment: That `dot` is the inner product.  The equivalent of `np.sum(y*y)`, a scalar.  To get a (70,70) you want the 'outer' product.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
np.multiply.outer(y,y)
```

or equally:

```
y = y[None,:]
y.T@y
```

example:

```
y = np.array([1,2,3])[None,:]
```

output:

```
#[[1 2 3]
# [2 4 6]
# [3 6 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reshape `y` from shape `(70,)` to `(70,1)` before multiplying the 2 matrices.

```py
# Reshape
y = y.reshape(70,1)

# Either below code would work
y*y.T

np.matmul(y,y.T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you need is the `@` matrix multiplication operator. `dot` method is only to compute dot product between vectors, what you want is matrix multiplication.

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(70, 1)
>>> (a @ a.T).shape
(70, 70)
```

---

### UPDATE:

Above answer is incorrect. `dot` does the same things if the array is 2D. See the docs [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#:%7E:text=Dot%20product%20of%20two%20arrays.&text=If%20both%20a%20and%20b,to%20multiply%20and%20using%20numpy.).

> `np.dot` computes the dot product of two arrays. Specifically,
>
> - If both a and b are 1-D arrays, it is inner product of vectors (without complex conjugation).
> - If both a and b are 2-D arrays, it is matrix multiplication, but using matmul or a @ b is preferred.

Simplest way to do what you want is to convert the vector to a matrix first using `np.matrix` and then using the `@`. Although, `dot` can also be used `@` is better because conventionally `dot` is used for vectors and `@` for matrices.

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(70)
(70,)
>>> a.shape
>>> a = np.matrix(a).T
>>> a.shape
(70, 1)
>>> (a @ a.T).shape
(70, 70)
```

Comment: `dot` does the same thing.  Try it, and read the docs.  (Your array is 2d, the OP's is 1d)

Comment: @hpaulj Good point. I will update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner?

```
np.dot(a[:, None], a[None, :])
```

`transpose` doesn't work on 1-D arrays, because you need atleast two axes to 'swap' them. This solution adds a new axis to the array; in the first argument, it looks like a column vector and has two axes; in the second argument it still looks like a row vector but has two axes.